# filter data frame based on multiple dynamic conditons, which depend on a subset of the data, eg. via applying a loop

Tags: r, loops, filter, dynamic, dplyr

I have data frame with hundreds of names and hundreds of values per name. Now I want filter some of the values based on some mathematical rule applied only to a certain subset of the data. A simplified example would filtering the max value for each name.

I can hard code it as shown below, but would love to avoid it.

```
library(dplyr)
##
names <- c('A', 'A', 'B', 'B')
values <- c(1,2,3,4)
df <- data.frame(names, values)
##
df%>%filter(names!='A' | values!=max(subset(df, names =='A')$values)
            ,names!='B' | values!=max(subset(df, names =='B')$values))
```

Desired ouptut:

```
  names values
1     A      1
2     B      3
```

I would consider creating a loop within a dplyr filter, that calculates the max value per name and then applies both conditions within the filter, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filtering out max value for each name:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(names) %>%
  filter(values != max(values))

# # A tibble: 2 x 2
# # Groups:   names [2]
#   names values
#   <chr>  <dbl>
# 1 A          1
# 2 B          3
```

Or if you mean removing the max values per name from the entire data frame, whenever they occur:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(names) %>%
  slice_max(values) %>%
  select(values) %>%
  anti_join(df, ., by = "values")

# # A tibble: 2 x 2
# # Groups:   names [2]
#   names values
#   <chr>  <dbl>
# 1 A          1
# 2 B          3
```

Comment: Seems like I was bit brain fried yesterday :-). Well, I over simplified my example here so that it did not match my original problem. Anyhow, you solved the question here and I solved my problem .-).

Answer (score 0):

An option in `base R`

```
subset(df, values != ave(values, names, FUN = max))
```